# What is electric permitivitty?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-fields, capacitance

I have read 10 different explanations for this in 10 minutes. By definition, to permit means to allow something, but some sites say that it is actually how much a material resists the electric field?

If I put two charges in a vacuum the vacuums ability to allow or resist (since I don't know) the electric field will be some value. Can someone in simple terms, like I'm five, explain what permittivity means? How did we find this value of permittivity in vacuum and why are the units F/m? No Wikipedia type answers please.

I just need to find an answer to this or I'm gonna go insane. Why does google even exist if you cant find simple answers to these questions?

Comment: Google is not peer reviewed science.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematically, the permitivity of freespace $\epsilon_0$ is a proportionality constant between a charge and the resultant electric field.

The higher the permitivity, the weaker field.

$\vec{E} \propto \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}}$

The permitivity of freespace is the universal proportionality constant and a fundamental constant, but inside materials the polar molecules may act as though there is a apparent change in the permitivity.

As when a material is exposed to an electric field, sometimes the resultant molecules create an opposing E field, leaving the field weaker.

Which can be moddelled as a permitivity different to that of freespace

Which is why you may think of it as "a materials ability to resist an electric field".

The alignment these molecules is complicated behaviour, and can be modeled like a harmonic osscillator

See:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_oscillator_model

With that being said, permitivity can change at specific resonant frequencies, which is why certain materials are colour they are.